# How to set network connection priority order under windows with wmic or VB-script?

Tags: windows, networking, wmic

Under Windows via "Network Adapters>Advanced Settings...>Adapters and Bindings>Connections" I can define the network connection priority order (I dont mean the provider order!).

But how can I do this with wmic or from a VB-script (if at all possible) to automate this process ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How can I define the network connection priority order from the command line

You can download [nvspbind](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Hyper-V-Network-VSP-Bind-cf937850) from Microsoft to do this.

> It can be used to enable or disable specific bindings on any NIC
>   and to query and change the NIC connection order.

See the `/+`, `/++`, `/-` and `/--` options.

Example:

Set the priority of the 'Wireless network connection' to the top of the binding order:

```
nvspbind.exe /++ "Wireless Network Connection" ms_tcpip
```

---

#### Hyper-V Network VSP Bind (nvspbind)

> nvspbind is a tool for modifying network bindings from the command
>   line. It is especially useful in Server Core environments with the
>   Hyper-V role enabled.
>
> It can be used to set the correct bindings for NICs used in Virtual
>   Networks.
>
> It can also be used to enable or disable specific bindings on any NIC
>   and to query and change the NIC connection order.
>
> It utilizes the INetCfg APIs documented on MSDN
>   (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms805265.aspx).
>
> Most options are documented in the readme and nvpsbind.txt which
>   download with the install.
>
> To get help run `nvspbind.exe /?`

```
C:\>nvspbind /?

Hyper-V Network VSP Bind Application 6.1.7690.0.
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Usage: nvspbind option NIC protocol

Options:
/n display NIC information only
/u unbind switch protocol from specified nic(s)
/b bind switch protocol to specified nic(s)
/d disable binding of specified protocol from specified nic(s)
/e enable binding of specified protocol to specified nic(s)
/r repair bindings on specified nic(s)
/o show NIC order for specified protocol
/+ move specified NIC up in binding order for specified protocol
/- move specified NIC down in binding order for specified protocol
/++ move specified NIC up to top of binding order for specified protocol
/-- move specified NIC down to bottom of binding order for specified protocol
```

> There are three variations:
>
> 1. Microsoft_Nvspbind_package.EXE is the standard 64 bit version for server core.
> 2. 32bit_Nvspbind_package.EXE is a 32 bit version that works on Vista and newer.
> 3. XP_Nvspbind_package.EXE is a reduced functionality 32 bit version that works on XP and newer.
>
> Although I work for Microsoft as a developer on the Hyper-V team, I must point out that as the license tab indicates this tool and documentation are provided "as-is". You bear the risk of using it. No express warranties, guarantees or conditions are provided. It is not supported or endorsed by Microsoft Corporation and should be used at your own risk.
>
> Verified on the following platforms

```
Windows Server 2012     Yes
Windows Server 2008 R2  Yes
Windows Server 2008     Yes
Windows Server 2003     No
Windows 8               Yes
Windows 7               No
Windows Vista           No
Windows XP              No
Windows 2000            No
```

> This script is tested on these platforms by the author. It is likely to work on other platforms as well.

Source [nvspbind](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Hyper-V-Network-VSP-Bind-cf937850)

Comment: thx for that.. sadly those tools are not official

Comment: @becks21 They are from Microsoft (but unsupported).

Comment: @becks21 You can probably write something in PowerShell or VBA that calls the same `INetCfg` API as the MS tool uses. I did search for code but couldn't find anything ready made for your exact requirements. I don't think you can do it directly with `wmic`